# Using now() function in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having a table with the following structure:

`ITEMS ('id' int(10), 'stock' int(10), 'date_updated' DATETIME);`

`id` is the primary key.

Some sample rows of my table are:

```
id  stock  date_updated
--  -----  -------------------
1   50     2011-11-05 05:00:00
2   40     2011-11-04 05:00:00
3   30     2011-11-03 05:00:00
4   20     2011-11-02 05:00:00
```

Suppose the time right now is: `2011-11-06 04:00:00`

**Problem:** Find out the sum of all the stock which are having `date_updated` within last 2 days.

**Example:** If I run query now, then it should output **90** i.e. 50+40 -- the sum of rows with `id = 1` and `id = 2` as these rows having `date_updated` column within last 2 days.

I am trying the following query but no success. Please help!

```
SELECT sum(stock)
FROM items
WHERE date_updated > now() - 2;
```

I am using PHP, MySQL, Apache on Windows machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use INTERVAL:

```
SELECT SUM(stock)
FROM items
WHERE date_updated > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
```